# Can't return value from a function call to main() correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to test this simple function, but Opt.status, Opt.Year values are not returned back to main(). Why? Please help as I am new to C++.I am using visual c++ to execute these codes.This is in my .cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    Easy_Task obj_EasyTask;
    TimeDateMonthOptions whatOptions=DATE;
    TOptions Opt;
    Opt.status=FALSE;
    Opt.Year=1970;

    printf("Enter code\n");
    scanf("%d",&obj_EasyTask.code);

    cout << "the code entered is: " << obj_EasyTask.code;
    obj_EasyTask.display2(obj_EasyTask.code);

    cout << "\nOutput: " << obj_EasyTask.show();

    printf("\nEnter the options that you prefer\n");
    scanf("%d",&whatOptions);


    obj_EasyTask.display3(whatOptions, Opt);

    cout << "\nOpt.Year: " << Opt.Year;

    if(Opt.status)
    {
        obj_EasyTask.x=(Opt.Year)& 0x00FF;
        obj_EasyTask.y=((Opt.Year)& 0xFF00)>>8;
        cout << "\nX: " << obj_EasyTask.x;
        cout << "\nY: " << obj_EasyTask.y;
        obj_EasyTask.Result=(obj_EasyTask.x)*(obj_EasyTask.y);
    }


    char holdWindow;
    std::cin >> holdWindow;
    return 0;
}


uint16_t Easy_Task::display2(uint16_t code) 
{
    if(code==1)
    {
        c = 7;
    }
    else
    {
        c = 9;
    }
    return c;

}

uint16_t Easy_Task::display3(TimeDateMonthOptions whtOptions, TOptions Opt)
{
    switch(whtOptions)
    { 
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            Opt.status=TRUE;
            cout << "\nStatus1: " << Opt.status;
            Opt.Year=1991;
            cout << "\nYear1: " << Opt.Year;
        break;
        case 7: 
            Opt.status=FALSE;
            cout << "\nStatus2: " << Opt.status;
            Opt.Year=2013;
            cout << "\nYear2: " << Opt.Year;
        break;
        default:
            Opt.status=FALSE;
            cout << "\nStatus3: " << Opt.status;
            Opt.Year=2010;
            cout << "\nYear3: " << Opt.Year;
        break;

    }
    return Opt.status, Opt.Year;

}
```

In my .h file I have the class defined as follows:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef unsigned short uint16_t;

#define TRUE 1;
#define FALSE 0;


typedef struct TOptions
{
    bool status;
    uint16_t Year;
};

typedef enum 
{
    YEAR,
    MONTH,
    DATE,
    HOURS,
    MINUTES,
    SECONDS,
    HUNDRETHS,
    UNDEFINED
}TimeDateMonthOptions;


class Easy_Task
{
public:

    uint16_t code, c, x,y, Result;
    uint16_t display2(uint16_t code);

    uint16_t show()
    {

        return c;
    };

    uint16_t display3(TimeDateMonthOptions whatOptions, TOptions Opt);

};
```

The problem I have is line:
        if(Opt.status)

Where it doesn't return the value of 1 but instead in takes the default value which was defined earlier. Why is this happening?

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problems, but you're asking for trouble with those evil macros with a `;` on the end. Just get rid of them and use the built-in `true` and `false` values. You would also be better off learning C++ from [a good modern book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242), not some ghastly blend of 1990-era C and C++.

Comment: Just a side note, in C++, this is illegal `return Opt.status, Opt.Year;`. You cannot return ***more than one items***. Change it to `return std::make_pair( Opt.status, Opt.Year );`.

Comment: @Hindol: It's not illegal, just useless and confusing. It would make more sense to return `Opt`, or modify it in place by passing by reference (which appears to be what the following code expects to happen).

Comment: @Mike, good point. I overlooked ';' while coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better still define a function to return TOptions
`TOptions Easy_Task::display3(...);` and return a structure.
Remember that you can only ever return **ONE SINGLE return value** from the function.

Comment: Even though the solution with passing the parameter by reference **with intention to modify it** works too, it makes **bad practice**: 1) in programming modifying the parameter is considered a **side-effect**, 2) the function should accept number of parameters and return a result.  And you should really learn to program well from the start, make it easy for other people to understand your code...

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the argument by *reference*:

```
uint16_t Easy_Task::display3(TimeDateMonthOptions whtOptions, TOptions& Opt) 
                                                                    //^
```

Otherwise, a copy of `Opt` is made and modified in the function and the caller will never see the changes.

Note that:

```
return Opt.status, Opt.Year;
```

does not somehow return two values. This is using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and will return the value `Opt.Year`. However, if you pass `Opt` by reference a return value is unrequired.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Note. It helps. The reference was the missing piece :)